# Why is 'wget --page-requisites' extremely slow

Tags: linux, performance, shell, wget

**Goal**

My goal is to download a single webpage to be fully functional offline in the same time it takes a browser to request and show the page.

**Problem**

The following command downloads a page and makes it fully functional offline, but it takes approximately 35 seconds where the hard refreshed browser requests and shows the page in about 5 seconds. Can someone please help me understand why my `wget` command is taking **so much longer** and how I can make it faster? Or is there any locations or chat groups where I can seek help? Sincere thanks in advance for any help anyone can provide.

```
wget --page-requisites --span-hosts --convert-links --adjust-extension --execute robots=off --user-agent Mozilla --random-wait https://www.invisionapp.com/inside-design/essential-steps-designing-empathy/
```

The command above provides the following time stats:

```
Total wall clock time: 35s
Downloaded: 248 files, 39M in 4.2s (9.36 MB/s)
```

Why is the wall clock time **significantly longer** than the download time and is there a way to make it faster?

**More info & attempted solutions**

- I removed `--random-wait` because I thought it might be adding time for each file request, but this did nothing.
- I thought the https protocol might slow it down with extra calls back and forth for each file so I added `--no-check-certificate`, but this did nothing.
- I read there could be an issue with IPv6 so I added `--inet4-only`, but this did nothing.
- I read the dns could slow things down so I added `--no-dns-cache`, but this did nothing.
- I thought perhaps wget was downloading the assets sequentially one at a time so I tried to run multiple commands concurrently with between 3 and 16 threads/processes by removing `--convert-links` adding `--no-clobber` in the hopes that with multiple files would be downloaded at the same time and after all files were downloaded that I could run the command again removing `--no-clobber` and `--page-requisites` and adding `--convert-links` to make it fully functional offline, but this did nothing. I also thought that multiple threads would speed things up because it would remove the latency of the https checks by doing multiple at a time, but I didn't observe this.
- I read an article about running the command as root user in case there were any limits on a given user, but this did nothing.

Comment: wget uses a single connection and downloads everything sequentially, web browsers use multiple connections and downloads everything simultaneously, that makes web browsers much faster. also browsers use transfer compression, wget does not (wtf wget?), that makes browsers faster.

Comment: To be honest, in this day and age, there are very few webpages that will work properly offline even when their static content is retrieved and stored verbatim. What are you _really_ trying to achieve? There's probably a better way.

Comment: @hanshenrik Sounds like a good _answer_ mate

Comment: voted to close as off-topic because this question belongs on superuser.com , not stackoverflow.com

Comment: @hanshenrik I considered most of the things you mentioned and attempted several solutions to get around them, but they didn't seem to work.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `wget --page-requisites` does exactly what I need, but I just need the total page downloads to be faster. But please let me know if you're aware of any other solutions that do exactly this, with high quality for majority of websites, that are runnable from the command line.

Comment: Seems like you didn't really read my comment

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I did indeed. I was just reiterating the question in which I'm asking for assistance. It's been working wonders for me. I'm open ears if you have any constructive feedback.

Answer (score 1):

wget uses a single connection and downloads everything sequentially, web browsers use multiple connections and downloads everything simultaneously, that makes web browsers much faster. also browsers use transfer compression, wget does not (wtf wget?), that makes browsers faster. also browsers have lots of stuff cached, which may make the browser appear faster because it's loading unchanged content from local disk/ram caches instead of actually downloading stuff, but even taking all of that into account, 5<->35 seconds seems like a lot

(one could make a script using libcurl's curl_multi api to do the same that your wget command is doing, that could use both multiple connections and transfer compression, but it would be a lot of work)

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. Good point on the compression. The time difference I mention compares wget to a hard web refresh so no cache and all requests should go directly to the host server. I did consider that the files were being retrieved sequentially, so one of my attempted solutions mentioned above tried to run multiple processes/threads with `--no-clobber` in the attempt to establish multiple connections where each program instance would check the currently downloaded files and skip them to request a new file that hasn't been downloaded, yet, but it didn't seem to work. Not sure why...